# Conditionally display a ViewController Xcode - iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication

I'm very new with Xcode and I would like to find a way to display something different if the user is logged in to my app or if he is not.

I have a tabbed application. The authenticated user should access directly to the tabbed views. But the user that is not should land on an authentication page.

My guess is that I need to have something like :

```
if (user) {
    // Do stuff if user logged in.
} else {
    // Display the authentication page.
}
```

But I have no idea on how to accomplish that and I didn't find anything about that. I'm looking for hints.

EDIT:

My question is not about how I could know if a user is authenticated or not, but how I can display a specific page in a case and an other page in an other case.

Where and how should I write the code, knowing that I already know how to distinguish an authenticated user :

```
   if (user is authenticated) {
// SHOW FIRSTVIEWCONTROLLER
   } else {
// SHOW SECONDVIEWCONTROLLER
  }
```

EDIT 2:

I have a tabbed application, with 3 tabs and a mainstoryboard (no xibs). I want to add a page, before the tabbed pages, where the user can authenticate.

So I need to display this viewController on a condition. If the user is not authenticated I show the page, if he is I show directly the tabbed pages.

Again, I don't want to know how to distinguish if the user is authenticated or not, I just wan't to know how I can display a ViewController if a condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Logged into what, exactly?

Comment: Logged into my app. I would like to have an authentication page that appears only the first time then cach the user session in order to display directly the tabbed section when the user comes back.

Comment: You need to provide more details. This question is too general. Maybe you could look into `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: The edit you provide is helpful - but you really do need to provide more details. All of this depends on how your app is set up. Are you using storyboards, XIBs, creating the views programmatically? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: wan't, does it mean want or don't want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would display the authentication page from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab. If you do this with presentViewController:animated:completion: with the animated parameter set to NO, the modal view will be the first thing the user sees. So, you can put the logic in that viewDidAppear method to determine whether or not to do that presentation.

Comment: That's the kind of hints I was looking for. Thank you very much !

Comment: I am doing this, but I want to leave the bottom tab bar so that the user logs in only if he wants. So I am using a push storyboard transition instead of a modal. The problem is that if the user taps again on that tab, the method `viewDidAppear` is not called. How do I prevent this?

Comment: @macool, I'm not sure I understand your concern. Are you saying that viewDidAppear is not being called, but you want it to be?

Comment: @rdelmar I just posted my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485491/ios-programmatically-display-a-view-controller-based-on-current-user

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to make use of [nsuserdefaults](/questions/tagged/nsuserdefaults) ([Apple Documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). To make use of this class, you save a value -- a bool, number, string, or some objects, that can be read from the next time the user opens your app.

You can use something like this to tell your app that the user has logged in.

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"loggedIn"];
```

Then the next time the user enters your app just see if he is logged in:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedIn"]) {
  //show information
} else { 
  //Show Login Screen
```

If you need to store actual credentials, just use `setObject: forKey:` and read back the objects with `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I think my question wasn't understood. I know how to distinguish if a user is authenticated or not. I just don't know how to do to tell "If he is, show this page, if he is not, show this page".

Comment: See the answer below, then.