# iOS Programmatically display a view controller based on current user

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, segue

I have a `PreferencesViewController` that shows information about current user:

[image: PreferencesViewController]

But it depends on the current user. If the user hasn't logged in yet, I am triggering a segue to `LoginViewController` on `PreferencesViewController` `viewWillAppear` method:

[image: LoginViewController]

The problem comes when the user hasn't signed in and taps again on the `Preferences` tab. It unwinds the segue back to `PreferencesViewController`, causing unexpected behaviour (`PreferencesViewController` should only be rendered when the user has logged in)

What is the best way to solve this? The approach I am using is okay? Can it be more optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the delegate method, tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:, and return NO if the user hasn't signed in.